# PDO fails when called inside a function

Tags: php, function, pdo, prepared-statement

I'm trying to use a function to execute all my PDO queries. I am experiencing a 500 error when using the function. I am able to execute the code successfully if I don't use the function.

you'll notice that the only difference between the working and non-working code blocks below is the use of the function.

Why does the code fail when called inside a function?

WORKS:

```
try {
  $conn = new PDO($dsn, $username, $password, $options);
}
catch (PDOException $e){
  echo "Connection failed: " . $e->getMessage();
}

$info = array();
$info['fname'] = $_POST['fname'];
$info['lname'] = $_POST['lname'];
$info['email'] = $_POST['email'];
$info['password'] = password_hash($_POST['password'], PASSWORD_DEFAULT);
$info['datecreated'] = date("Y-m-d H:i:s");

$sql = "INSERT INTO Users (fname, lname, email, password, datecreated)
VALUES (:fname, :lname, :email, :password, :datecreated)";

try {
    $stmt=$conn->prepare($sql);
    $stmt->execute($info);
}
catch (PDOException $e)
{
    echo $sql . "PDO query failed: <br>" . $e->getMessage();
}
```

DOESN'T WORK

```
try {
  $conn = new PDO($dsn, $username, $password, $options);
}
catch (PDOException $e){
  echo "Connection failed: " . $e->getMessage();
}

$info = array();
$info['fname'] = $_POST['fname'];
$info['lname'] = $_POST['lname'];
$info['email'] = $_POST['email'];
$info['password'] = password_hash($_POST['password'], PASSWORD_DEFAULT);
$info['datecreated'] = date("Y-m-d H:i:s");

$sql = "INSERT INTO Users (fname, lname, email, password, datecreated)
VALUES (:fname, :lname, :email, :password, :datecreated)";

function pdoquery ($sql, $info){
    
    try {
        $stmt=$conn->prepare($sql);
        $stmt->execute($info);
    }
    catch (PDOException $e)
    {
        echo $sql . "PDO query failed: <br>" . $e->getMessage();
    }
}

pdoquery($sql,$info);
```

Comment: Where did you pass $conn in function

Comment: @PushpendraSingh I edited my question to include $conn. Hope the helps.

Comment: You did not add $conn in function pdoquery

Comment: Please do not catch exceptions pointlessly!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try following

```
$info = array();
$info['fname'] = $_POST['fname'];
$info['lname'] = $_POST['lname'];
$info['email'] = $_POST['email'];
$info['password'] = password_hash($_POST['password'], PASSWORD_DEFAULT);
$info['datecreated'] = date("Y-m-d H:i:s");

$sql = "INSERT INTO Users (fname, lname, email, password, datecreated)
VALUES (:fname, :lname, :email, :password, :datecreated)";

function pdoquery ($sql, $info, $conn){
    
    $stmt=$conn->prepare($sql);
    $stmt->execute($info);
    return $stmt;
}

pdoquery($sql,$info, $conn);
```

In a nutshell, you forgot to pass `$conn` to your function.

Comment: Should `$conn` be added by *reference*? Or doesnt matter? As in `function pdoquery ($sql, $info, &$conn){`.

Comment: @GetSet no, it shouldn't.